# Adding "this" reference to Array fails in Java Constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I am absolute clueless why the following code keeps throwing NullpointerExceptions. I was not able to understand or debug this (its stripped down code from a larger class)...

The code is based on the "Enum Pattern" and I want to keep a List/Map of all "Constants" that are contained in the class (I might be using Reflection for this but using a List/Map is much easier...)

```
   public class Country {

        public static final Country SWITZERLAND = new Country("SWITZERLAND");

        private static ArrayList<Country> countries = new ArrayList<Country>();

        private  Country(String constname) {     
             //constname is currently not used (I will use it for a Key in a Map)
            System.out.println(constname);
            System.out.println("Ref debug:"+this);

            //Ad this to the Countries
            Country.countries.add(this);
        }
    }
```

Help would be very much appreciated. What am I missing here?

Comment: It was a gerat learning: to sum it up: THE ORDER OF STATIC INITIALIZERS IS RELEVANT!!!

Thanks so much to all who answered!!

Comment: Self-registering constructors are really not a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on what Konrad said, the static variable initializers are executed in textual order (as specified in [JLS section 8.7](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.7)). If you put the `ArrayList` first, it will work:

```
public class Country {    
    private static ArrayList<Country> countries = new ArrayList<Country>();

    public static final Country SWITZERLAND = new Country("SWITZERLAND");

...
```

Konrad's suggestion of using a static constructor to keep the order clearly specified is a good one though.

Are you using Java "pre 1.5"? If not, use a straight enum...

Comment: +1 … I’m not actually very fluent in Java, hence I wasn’t sure about the order of initialization. Since Jon says that it’s textual, this solution is superior to the `static` block (IMHO).

Answer (score 5):

`SWITZERLAND`, being static, is potentially initialized *before* `countries`, which is also `static`. Therefore, `countries` is still `null` in the constructor call of `SWITZERLAND`.

To force a well-defined order of initialization, use a `static` block:

```
public class Country {

    public static final Country SWITZERLAND;

    private static ArrayList<Country> countries;

    static {
        countries = new ArrayList<Country>();
        SWITZERLAND = new Country("SWITZERLAND");
    }
}
```

Comment: Order of initialization is always well-defined. It is performed in textual order. +1 for static initialization block. The order of execution is more clear for the reader this way.

Answer (score 4):

Because I think this deserves more than the cursory mention Jon gave it:

**The "typesafe enum pattern" is obsolete!**

Unless you are forced to use an ancient Java version (pre 1.5, which isn't even supported anymore by Sun), you should use Java's [real Enums](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), which save you a lot of work and hassles (because old-style typesafe enums are very hard to get right) and are just all around awesome.

Answer (score 1):

'Country' constructor call to initialize `SWITZERLAND` static field happens before initialization of `countries` list. If you change order of static field definition it will work better.

Answer (score -1):

I think code bellow may work .Constructor of class have to define as public method not private.

Country(String constname) {
             //constname is currently not used (I will use it for a Key in a Map)
            System.out.println(constname);
            System.out.println("Ref debug:"+this);

```
        //Ad this to the Countries
        Country.countries.add(this);
    }
```

Comment: The visibility of the constructor has got nothing to do with the problem.